# ng-template not getting refreshed on clicking the button

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following controller:

```
function _deleteServiceInstance(serviceInstanceId) {
    self.hasServerErrors = false;
    self.serverErrors = [];
    var flag = 1;
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete the service instance in this environment region?")) {
        for (var i = 0; i < self.serviceInstanceDeployments.length; i++) {
            var obj = self.serviceInstanceDeployments[i];
            if (obj.state === "ACTIVE")
                flag = 0;
        }
        if (flag === 0)
        {
            self.hasServerErrors = true;
            self.serverErrors = ["Please delete the active deployments before deleting the service instance"];
            // $window.location.reload();
            $scope.$apply();
            return self.serverErrors;
        };
    }
}
```

The following is the HTML:

```
   <a uib-popover-template="ctrl.deleteServiceInstanceTemplate" popover-title="Delete service instance"
           popover-placement="auto bottom" popover-trigger="outsideClick">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
                Delete
            </button>
   </a>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="deleteServiceInstance.html">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <form name="ctrl.delete.form" class="form-horizontal" novalidate>
                <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error' : ctrl.hasServerErrors}">
                    <label class="col-sm-12 control-label">Are you sure?
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ctrl.deleteServiceInstance(ctrl.serviceInstance.id)"
                                ng-disabled="ctrl.purge.form.$invalid">Yes</button>
                        <span ng-show="ctrl.hasServerErrors" class="help-block" ng-repeat="serverError in ctrl.serverErrors">{{serverError}}</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Basically, there is a delete button which opens as a pop-up. It asks for confirmation if I am sure of deleting something. If I press yes, it checks if there are any deployments in active state. If there are, it shows an error. Now, the problem is, when I click on the delete button for the second time, it shows the same error even when I haven't pressed yes. It keeps on showing the same error until the page is refreshed.

Edit: I have declared the _deleteServiceInstance like this in my controller:

```
self.deleteServiceInstance = _deleteServiceInstance
```

Comment: From where you are calling? `_deleteServiceInstance` ?

Comment: @AdnanUmer, see my edit. I have declared it in my controller, and I am calling the deleteServiceInstance method from the template I have defined.

Answer (score 0):

> You should clear the messages while clicking the `delete` button event, instead of  `yes` button click event

```
<button type="button" ng-click="clearMessages" class="btn btn-danger">
                Delete
            </button>
```

Controller

```
function _clearMessages() {
    self.hasServerErrors = false;
    self.serverErrors = [];
}


self.clearMessages= _clearMessages
```